# Can an Indian Deemed to be University suppress the fundamental rights of a student?

Tags: human-rights

I am pursuing a BTech mechanical degree from Vellore Institute of Technology, Vellore, Tamil Nadu, India. I will point out  the rules here:

-Students cannot go out of the campus for first three months.
-Only handshakes are permitted between opposite sexes inside the campus.
-Students have to take permission of a 'proctor'(mentor) before exiting campus.
-Even if they permit to go out, it is for just 4 hours on week days, 6 hours for weekends. For girls, it is even worser, they are required to call their parents to talk with the proctor before going out.

Student unions are strictly dealt with by the management, they expel any students who rebel against the rules. A student was expelled just for taking a survey about the rules there.

Is their practice acceptable by the law?

PS: I am new here, sorry if I posted at the wrong place

Answer (score 1):

This is completely legal, and is covered by the concept of a contract. As a "deemed" university, VIT is private property, and no person has a legal right to attend the institution without the assent of VIT. They offer something of value (an education), presumably in exchange for something of value (money), and subject to certain conditions which include whatever the code of conduct states. In accepting their offer, you agree to those conditions. If you do not abide by those conditions, you are in breach of contract, and they can expel you (terminate the contract).

The Government of India might decide that certain practices are against the law, so perhaps Parliament could deem as contrary to public policy the requirement that a student obtain permission to exit campus. If that were to happen, then the requirement to obtain permission would be unenforceable, and leaving without permission would not be deemed to be breach of contract.

The situation would be different in the case of a governmental university, to the extent that the law says that a person has a legal right to attend the university.

Comment: I don't know what the law is in India, but in the US the provision with different rules for men and women about leaving campus could be a violation of the Civil Rights Act.

Comment: For example. I have not been able to find an official copy of the policy. I think though that different rules for males and females w.r.t. government action would violate Art. 14-16, but I don't find specific legislation analogous to the US C.R.A.

Comment: So, it would be alright for a student to leave the campus without permission? And yes, the exit rules are stricter for girls.

Comment: Hello, are you scared to comment here?

Comment: What?? Can you post these purported rules?

Comment: I am unable to find some reliable document stating these rules, I came to know these rules only when I attended the orientation programme on the first day, I'll keep searching for an official doc.